# When do you get Cattail?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I've been playing adventure to the pool do I get Cattail in roof or fog?

Answer (score 7):

The Cattail isn't unlocked through normal play.

It is an upgrade to the Lily Pad (which you automatically unlock at the start of the pool levels) and is available from Crazy Dave for $10000.